# SWIG/Python detected wxPasswordEntryDialog Memory Leak

Tags: python, memory, wxpython, swig, memory-leaks

I'm using a wx.PasswordEntryDialog to get a password from the user, but every time I create a PasswordEntryDialog I get this error:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'wxPasswordEntryDialog *', no destructor found.
```

Here is one of the places that causes it:

```
def getpass():
    dialog = wx.PasswordEntryDialog(None, 'Enter your password')
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        value = dialog.GetValue()
    else:
        value = None
    del dialog
    return value
```

Comment: How are you wrapping `PasswordEntryDialog`, i.e. where did the SWIG interface come from and what does it contain?

Comment: @Flexo: wxPython is built using SWIG.  It seems that this is an oddity with wxPython.  The asker almost certainly hasn't been using SWIG directly here.

Comment: Luke is right, I'm using wxPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you can get rid of the message by replacing the line

```
del dialog
```

with

```
dialog.Destroy()
```

(I'm using wxWidgets/wxPython 2.9.3, if that's relevant.)

Comment: Interesting, I did wonder if it was a pre-built interface or something the OP had put together. Do you know what version of SWIG was used to build this version of wxPython?

Comment: @Flexo: no, and I'm not sure it's relevant.  All I know is that I was able to reproduce the message reported by the asker, and making the replacement I describe removes this message.

Comment: I had a funny feeling there were some bugs related to this in various older releases of SWIG.